# gzip: CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz: not in gzip format

Tags: gzip, gunzip

I'm trying to expand a file named CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz by using  **guzip CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz** , but always I have this error **gzip: CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz: not in gzip format** . can any one tell me what is the cause and how to fix it.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, the file is just not in gzip format.

Comment: I now that , I don't understand the meaning of this error and I don't now how to access to my file ,I tried to run **mv CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz CHARTEVENTS.csv ** and when I tried to open the file I don't understand any thing . @DavidDai did you now how to fix it ?

Comment: Try the file command explained in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: if you can share the file. Maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, it should tell you what format your file really is:

```
file CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz
```

An example:

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo 'test' >test.txt
root@ubuntu:~# mv test.txt test.gz
root@ubuntu:~# file test.gz
test.gz: ASCII text
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: this is the output  of **file CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz** 
**CHARTEVENTS.csv.gz: data**

Comment: That means you'll have to ask whoever created this file what exactly the file is. Or find other clever ways to determine what's in the file. It's definitely not in gzip or csv format, because if it's either the `file` command can definitely tell.

Comment: @elabedhoussem no idea what you mean